# Creating multi-scale, nested, ordinal bar charts with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making an interactive version of [this infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V01B6.jpg)

This is proving difficult in D3. There will be multiple ordinal scales:

- One Y scale for each country
- One Y scale for each period in each country
- One X scale

For each period, there will be two values (visualized as two different colored bars). The main problem is that not all countries will have three periods; the data does not take a completely even shape. This is to say that some segments of the first Y scale will have different heights. I'm not sure how to take care of this.

Suppose I have this data:

```
CountryName Period  ValueA  ValueB
Argentina   2004-2008   12  5
Argentina   2004-2013   10  5
Argentina   2008-2013   8   4
Bolivia 2002-2008   4   2
Bolivia 2002-2013   6   18
Brazil  2003-2008   9   2
Brazil  2003-2013   2   19
Brazil  2008-2013   1   3
```

And I use the d3.nest() function:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.CountryName; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.Period; })
  .map(data);
```

Now I'll have the data in the form that I want it, but note that there is some missing data - Bolivia only has two periods of data, in this case. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06wea4x6/) for this, but as you can see, it has some problems. The height of the bars should be the same, always. I want to use yScale.rangeBand(), but the problem is that some countries will have three periods, where some will only have two. I also need to find a way to display the country names and periods to the left of the bars

If anybody has a better means of approaching this problem, please let me know. I have been struggling for this for a couple of days. As you can see from the JSFiddle, I only have one yScale but I'm sure it's preferable to use two given my situation - I do not know how to implement this.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You may not really need the nesting.
This is a special case bar chart so you will need to make axis' bars ticks grids all by yourself.

I have added comments in the code for you to follow

```js
    var outerWidth = 1000;
    var outerHeight = 500;
    var margin = {
      left: 100,
      top: 0,
      right: 100,
      bottom: 90
    };
    var barPadding = 0.6;
    var barPaddingOuter = 0.3;
    var innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    //make your svg
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", outerWidth)
      .attr("height", outerHeight);
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + 30 + ")");
    //the axis is on the right
    var xAxisG = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 10 + ")")

    //the y axis is common for all
    var yAxisG = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis");

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, innerWidth]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, innerHeight], barPadding, barPaddingOuter);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
      .outerTickSize(0);

    function render(data) {
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("top")
        //.tickValues([-5, -4, -3, 0, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
        .outerTickSize(0)
        .innerTickSize(-1 * outerHeight);

      xScale.domain([0, 30]);

      //this will make the y axis labels.
      var country = "";
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.CountryName == country) {
          d.label = d.Period
        } else {
          d.label = d.Period
          d.heading = d.CountryName;
        }
        country = d.CountryName;
      });
      var labels = data.map(function(d) {
        return d.label
      });
      //set the domain for all y labels,
      yScale.domain(labels);
      //makes the x Axis
      xAxisG.call(xAxis);
      //makes the y Axis
      yAxisG.call(yAxis);
      //make the bar chart for valueB
      var bars = g.selectAll(".ValueA").data(data);
      bars.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand() / 2);
      bars
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return xScale(0)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return yScale(d.label);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          console.log(d.ValueA)
          return xScale(d.ValueA);
        })
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("class", "ValueA");
      //make the bar chart for valueB
      var bars = g.selectAll(".ValueB").data(data);
      bars.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand() / 2);
      bars
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return xScale(0)
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return yScale.rangeBand() / 2 + yScale(d.label);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d) {
          return xScale(d.ValueB);
        })
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .attr("class", "ValueA");
      //make grid lines
      var lines = g.selectAll(".xLine").data(data.filter(function(d){return !(d.heading == undefined) }));
      lines.enter().append("line")
      lines
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return (yScale(d.label) - yScale.rangeBand())
        })
        .attr("x2", innerWidth)
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return (yScale(d.label) - yScale.rangeBand())
        })
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("class", "xLine")
        .style("display", function(s) {
          if((yScale(s.label) - yScale.rangeBand()) < 0){
            return "none";//not show grids when y comes negative
          }
        });
      
      //make heading
      var headings = g.selectAll(".heading").data(data.filter(function(d){return !(d.heading == undefined) }));
      headings.enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d){return d.heading})
      .attr("x", -100)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
          return (yScale(d.label) - yScale.rangeBand()) +30
      })

    }

    function type(d) {
      d.ValueA = +d.ValueA;
      d.ValueB = +d.ValueB;
      console.log(d)
      return d;
    }    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/e2dff83329af684cde78/raw/f85ce83497553c360d2af5d5dcf269390c44022f/cities.csv", type, render);
```

```css
.tick line {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    
    .xLine {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    
    .axis text {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    .axis .label {}
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .y.axis path,
    .y.axis line {
      stroke: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this! It definitely helps. I had some questions though- I noticed that the chart does not show the correct values per the data. For example, Argentina,  2004-2008,  should have 12 and 5, but it renders on your snippet as 17 and 10. It looks like the width is off by 5 units?


Also, I don't understand this anonymous function:

`.style("display", function(s) {
          if((yScale(s.label) - yScale.rangeBand()) < 0){
            return "none";//not show grids when y comes negative
          }`

Why is it called with function(s) instead of function(d) ?

Can you please take a look?

Comment: I have fixed the 5 unit shift that was the reason why databar @ 17 comes 12.
You can write this : `style("display", function(s){}` or `style("display", function(d){}` its just the parameter name which is changed instead of `d` i am making it `s` ..simple..:)

The purpose of the  function `style("display", function(s) { if((yScale(s.label) - yScale.rangeBand()) < 0){ return "none";//not show grids when y comes negative }` is to hide horizontal grid for argentina coz it comes negative. comment this line and see it for yourself what happens and what this line does.

I have updated my fiddle abov.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when there are multiple labels that are the same. When I use data that has two different countries but with the same period, it puts two bars in the same Y position...

Comment: whats your new dataset i ll have a look

Comment: Hi - I have uploaded a new CSV here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyniclone/be6802c965ab18dc6e00/raw/cd1461a8d4fd9e4f6897a754b7f4b96ed0dd9eae/inequality.csv  PLEASE note that I have changed it to ValueB and ValueG.